# Odoo 10 ParseError: "External ID not found in the system: website_sale.checkout"

Tags: xml-parsing, odoo, odoo-10

I get ParseError: "External ID not found in the system: website_sale.checkout" Although template exists in odoo/addons/website_sale. It worked for some time and then crashed.

```xml
<template id="checkout_add_delivery" inherit_id="website_sale.checkout">
            <xpath expr="//a[@class='btn btn-default mb32']" position="replace">
                <form action="/shop/payment" method="post" class="s_website_form form-horizontal container-fluid mt32"
                      enctype="multipart/form-data" data-force_action="sale.order" data-model_name="sale.order" data-success_page="/shop/payment">
                    <div class="form-group">


                        <p>Delivery Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"/></p>
                        <span>Delivery Time</span>
                        <select>
                            <option>08:00</option>
                            <option>08:15</option>
                            <option>08:30</option>
                        </select>

                        <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" t-att-value="request.csrf_token()"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </xpath>
        </template>
```

Comment: make sure to website_sale in depends in your openerp.py

Comment: @CherifOdoo maybe make it an answer? :-P

Comment: He didn't respond so no need

Comment: Thought that, but then it shows. Unmet dependencies: website_sale.